# SQLITE unfortunaly stopped

Tags: java, android, sqlite

goodmornig, I have a problem with the creation of database on Android studio. the code have no problem but the app say "unfortunately stoppep". how can i solve this problem?

```
package com.example.maria.database;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
DatabaseHelper myDB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and there is the other activity

```
package com.example.maria.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "student.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2= "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "SURNAME";
public static final String COL_4 = "MARKS";



public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table" + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY        AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, intnewVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}
}
```

Comment: please attach log report so we can understand the problem.

Comment: _"the code have no problem but the app say "unfortunately stoppep""_ So the code _probably_ has a problem.

Comment: Use `"create table "` instead of `"create table"` . probably issue is occurring due to no space between `table` and `TABLE_NAME`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have **missed space** in query:

```
db.execSQL("create table" + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY        AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)");
```

It should be:

```
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY        AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please upload Logcat Output.

I think there must be some error In create table. . In most cases this happens

Also make open and close methods before calling any other methods.

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{ public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "student.db"; public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table"; public static final String COL_1 = "ID"; public static final String COL_2= "NAME"; public static final String COL_3 = "SURNAME"; public static final String COL_4 = "MARKS";

You have used upper case for column name. Make it lower case and try.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ef1la33vplf8vli/TAG.pdf?dl=0

Comment: i fix the space and the app seems to operate but the log is the same (in the link above)

Comment: have you tries with lower case name for column ? Which Solution Worked ?Please Tell

Comment: With upper or lower case is the same..the only problem was the space